# Postgres : Finding time range where data is missing

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

given the following table

```
2019-11-13  data_exist
2019-11-14  []
2019-11-15  []
2019-11-16  []
2019-11-17  data_exist
2019-11-18  []
2019-11-19  []
2019-11-20  data_exist
```

I want the time-range where `[]` occurred.

```
2019-11-14 2019-11-16
2019-11-18 2019-11-19
```

How do i use groupby or window function to find the date range where `[]` occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select cast('2019-11-13' as date )as ddate,  'data_exist' as ddata into tmp
union select '2019-11-14',  '[]'
union select '2019-11-15',  '[]'
union select '2019-11-16',  '[]'
union select '2019-11-17',  'data_exist'
union select '2019-11-18',  '[]'
union select '2019-11-19',  '[]'
union select '2019-11-20',  'data_exist';




with cte as
(select ddate from tmp a where ddata = '[]')

select startdate, max(enddate) as enddate from
(
    select min(startdate) as startdate, enddate from
    (
      select a.ddate as startdate, b.ddate as enddate, EXTRACT(DAY FROM b.ddate::TIMESTAMP - a.ddate::TIMESTAMP) as diffdate, 
      (select count(*)-1 from cte c where c.ddate between a.ddate and b.ddate)  as countdate 
      from cte a cross join cte b 
      where EXTRACT(DAY FROM b.ddate::TIMESTAMP - a.ddate::TIMESTAMP) = (select count(*)-1 from cte c where c.ddate between a.ddate and b.ddate) and a.ddate <> b.ddate
      and (select count(*)-1 from cte c where c.ddate between a.ddate and b.ddate) > 0
    )b
    group by enddate
)b
group by startdate
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think this breaks down if there is only one [] in the gap (e.g. add 
union select '2019-11-21',  '[]' 
union select '2019-11-22',  'data_exist';
to your example). That is probably pretty easy to fix but I think I have a simpler method so will post an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from zip will work (with a slight tweak as per my comment) however I'd approach this a bit differently so thought it was worth posting an alternative. Using the same setup as zip the query could be:

```
select 
ddate as fromdate,
(select ddate 
    from tmp itmp where 
    itmp.ddate < 
        (select ddate from tmp itmp2 
         where itmp2.ddata <> '[]' and itmp2.ddate > tmp.ddate 
         order by ddate limit 1) 
    order by ddate desc limit 1
) as todate 
from tmp 
where 
ddata = '[]' and 
(select ddata from tmp it where it.ddate < tmp.ddate order by it.ddate desc limit 1) <> '[]'
order by ddate
```

Another way of doing this applies if, as I suspect, by [] you mean there are no records (and you need to base the query on when there IS data). In that case something along the lines of the below would work (I have stuck to using zip's test data; the query can be simplified further if [] does mean no records).

```
select ddate + interval '1' day as fromdate, 
(select ddate from tmp itmp where itmp.ddata <> '[]' and itmp.ddate > tmp.ddate order by ddate limit 1) - interval '1' day as todate 
from tmp 
where 
ddata <> '[]' 
and (select ddata from tmp it where it.ddate > tmp.ddate order by it.ddate desc limit 1) <> '[]'
order by ddate
```